# gstreamer - latency sending RTP video

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm setting up a wireless streaming rig. I have two web cams a C920 that works nicely. My Logitech Brio camera is delayed causing the camera to be out of sync while both are displayed. I've tried using different encoders (MJPG, YUY2, NV12).

Do you know how to reduce the latency? Alternatively I could increase the latency on the C920 camera so they are in sync.

I've tried H264 & H265 with the same results.

**Server / Encoder**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x265enc ! h265parse ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.54 port=8555
```

**Client / Decoder**

```
udpsrc port=8555 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H265, payload=(int)96" ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! avdec_h265 ! video.
```

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

The working web cam is a c920 which has a h264 encoder built in. That explains the difference.

Comment: This has solved it for me:

gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! image/jpeg,format=MJPG,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=60/1 ! jpegparse ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.54 port=8555

Answer (score 0):

I moved to using MJPG with the Logitech Brio

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! image/jpeg,format=MJPG,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=60/1 ! jpegparse ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.54 port=8555
```

A better x264enc line set

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=6000 pass=pass1 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency sliced-threads=true threads=6 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.54 port=8555
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).